# Hide attribute for configurable product in frontend

Tags: configurable-product, frontend

I have a configurable product which shows 4 dropdowns in the frontend on the product detail page. I'd like to hide some of them, and was hoping to achieve this using "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end" setting for the attributes, but they still appear in the frontend. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You add a simple product and then assign into configurable product right

Answer (score 1):

That means you chose all four attributes when you created your configurable product.
Now these values must be chosen by customer. You can not hide it.

**Solution:**
Create same configurable product but only select what attributes you need to show in frontend.